# Position divs with different on the bottom of parent div, next to eachother

Tags: html, css, tabs, alignment

How can I position divs with different heights to the bottom of parent div, next to eachother.

like I do in the code but alignment to the bottom.

the divs represent tabs, where the red on is the current active tab and the grey ones non active tabs

```css
 .pane{
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 500px;
            height: 120px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
        .sec{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 35%;
            height: 80%;
            background-color: red;
            border-right: dashed;

        }
        .thir{
            float: left;
            width: 15%;
            height: 70%;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: grey;
            border-right: dashed;
        }
```

```html
<div class="pane">
            <div class="sec"></div>
            <div class="thir"></div>
            <div class="thir"></div>
            <div class="thir"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using a flex box and aligning the items to the flex-end.

```css
.pane{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: flex-start;
       align-items: flex-end;

            width: 500px;
            height: 120px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
        .sec{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 35%;
            height: 80%;
            background-color: red;
            border-right: dashed;

        }
        .thir{
            float: left;
            width: 15%;
            height: 70%;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: grey;
            border-right: dashed;
        }
```

```html
<div class="pane">
            <div class="sec"></div>
            <div class="thir"></div>
            <div class="thir"></div>
            <div class="thir"></div>
    </div>
```